# Stretchy Header CollectionVC with searchBar swift (programmatically)

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with a headerView, I would like it to become a stretchy header when scroll as shown in the given examples.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2zNX.gif)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLlYR.gif)

Here's a piece of my code :

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let y = -scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let height = max( y, 80 )
    print(height)
    headerView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)   
}
```

Any ideas how to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/twitteranimation & plenty of others in CocoaControls ? Looking for "Header" should suffice

Comment: i try it, didn't works... i need programmatically(without storyboard)

Comment: There are others, there are code that can inspire you. Even if it’s in storyboard you can replicate it by code.